# Removing user inserted image tags with PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to remove any user inserted image tags while allowing my own image icon. I have this

```
$post = 'Here is an image <img src="imgage.jpg" /> to check
         and my icon <img src="/images/ImageLink.jpg" />';

$imgcheck = true;
$stringstart = 0;

while($imgcheck == 'true'){
    if($stringstart = strpos($post,'<img',$stringstart)){
        if ($stringend = strpos($post,'>',$stringstart)){
            $strlength = $stringend - $stringstart;
            $substring = substr($post,$stringstart,$strlength);
            if (!preg_match('/src="\/images\/ImageLink.jpg"/',$substring)){
                $post = str_replace($substring, "", $post);
            }
            else{
                $stringstart = $stringend;
            }

        }
        else{
            $imgcheck = 'false';
        }
    }
    else{
            $imgcheck = 'false';
    }

}
```

I would like this to return

```
Here is an image to check and my icon <img src="/images/ImageLink.jpg" />
```

I seem to be getting an error on one of the strpos functions but cannot figure out why.

Update:Thank you hakre. That answer is much more elegant. I did finally make the code work with

```
$imgcheck = true;
$stringstart = 0;

while($imgcheck == 'true'){
    if($stringstart = strpos($post,'&lt;img',$stringstart)){
        if ($stringend = strpos($post,'&gt;',$stringstart)){
            $strlength = $stringend - $stringstart +4;
            $substring = substr($post,$stringstart,$strlength);
            if (!preg_match('~src="\/images\/ImageLink.jpg"~',$substring)){
                $post = str_replace($substring, "", $post);
            }
            else{
                $stringstart = $stringend;
            }

        }
        else{
            $imgcheck = 'false';
        }
    }
    else{
            $imgcheck = 'false';
    }

}
```

with `&lt;` and `&gt;` used because I am using a div with contenteditable=true for user input. This could also be used for a text area by simply replacing `&lt;` and `&gt;` with `<img` and `>` respectively as well as changing

```
$strlength = $stringend - $stringstart +4;
```

to

```
$strlength = $stringend - $stringstart +1;
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Maybe it's better to look around the `strip_tags()` method.

Comment: strip_tags would also remove my image icons which are inserted with jquery.

Comment: So be clear in your question title. I'm not familiar with RegEx, In an easy way you can first replace your icon tags with a specific mark like `[MyIcon]` next `strip_tags` then replace `[MyIcon]`s with your icon tag. It's dirty but a good trick.

Comment: That is clever and I will fall back on that method if I cannot find a suitable alternative.

Comment: @buck54321: Please add your solution as an answer below and select it as "the answer". This is how this site works (and yes, you can answer your own question, it's nothing wrong with that). This helps keeping this site working, so thanks in advance!

Comment: @hakre: My rep is not high enough to answer my own question. I have to wait 8 hours. I will update then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a HTML parser for the job, for example `DOMDocument`.

The following example code will put your html fragment into a div with the id `post` so it can be identified:

```
$post = 'Here is an image <img src="imgage.jpg" /> to check
         and my icon <img src="/images/ImageLink.jpg" />';

$post = '<div id="post">'.$post.'</div>';
```

Then the `DOMDocument` is created and the html loaded into it. Additionally the container div is made available as a variable by it's id:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($post);
$container = $doc->getElementById('post');
```

The next step is to select all images you want to remove. This is done with xpath. The xpatch expression will then be queried with the `$container` as reference:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);    
$expression = './/img[@src != "/images/ImageLink.jpg"]';
$nodes = $xpath->query($expression, $container);
```

The next step is to iterate over all found elements and to remove them:

```
foreach($nodes as $node)
{
    $parent = $node->parentNode;
    $parent->removeChild($node);
}
```

Finally the changed HTML needs to be aquired by taking everything out of the `$container`:

```
$innerHTML = '';
foreach($container->childNodes as $child) {
    $innerHTML .= $node->ownerDocument->saveXML($child);
}
```

Now everything is in

```
echo $innerHTML;
```

which will give you:

```
Here is an image  to check
         and my icon <img src="/images/ImageLink.jpg"/>
```

Hope this is useful.